# How to verify Java nullability annotations for Kotlin?

Tags: java, kotlin

Our team is writing a Java library which we want to be interoperable with Kotlin. To make it easier to use, we are adding [Kotlin nullability annotations](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#nullability-annotations) to our Java API.

Since this a manual process, there could easily be human error in the process. Is there some way to verify that our annotations on the API are correct or at least internally consistent?

Comment: Did you have a look at: https://github.com/uber/NullAway ?